# Is persistence a property of a database?

Tags: database-theory, databases

I was having a discussion in another forum on this topic, and I couldn’t get a satisfactory answer. Originally, a statement was made that a redis data store couldn’t be considered a database because it’s not persisted to disk. I queried that, because I didn’t see why persistence is a required property of a database. I understand a database to simply be some structured/organised data.

So: is persistence a required property of a database, and why?

Answer (score 3):

The databases I've seen are persistent.  But rather than trying to figure out the "one true meaning" of the word database, if this aspect matters in a specific context, then I suggest you just be explicit about how you are using the word.  That's probably best in any case if this is critical.

A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.  (Shakespeare)